# jquery ajax success action arguments not work correctly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Here is my ajax success function:

```
success: function (data) {
    if(data == 'logged') {
        window.location.href = window.location.href;
    } else {
        $("#result").html(data);
    }
},
```

In this action when my php script return 'logged' text redirect don't start but also script execute stuff from else argument and insert to my #result div returned 'logged' text.

This also happen when my php script don't return 'logged' text but return other stuff.. returned data is inserted to #result div ... seems this function completly skips the if/else arguments.. why it happen?

Comment: what is the response you are receiving ? Try logging to console and see

Comment: what is your dataType?

Comment: Open your developer console, execute `console.log(data)` within this handler, and show us the result.

Comment: Are you having a space in the response you are receiving ?

Comment: responses are correctly.. based on php script each time i got data what i want... the problem is when the success function must use returned data and do something else based on the if/else arguments... my php script returns only two different texts via `echo`, 'logged' or other statement when problem is with data sended to this script...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only reason i can think is you might be getting a space with the word `logged`. Ideally you should fix that in your server side to send the trimmed/correct response. But if you want to do that in the client side for any reason, you may use the `trim()`.

The `trim()` method removes whitespace characters like space, tab and no-break space etc from both ends of a string. method. Also consider using `===` (*Identity operator*)for the comparison when you know both operands are of same type( In our case both are string type).

```
success: function (data) {
    if(data.trim() === 'logged') {
        window.location.href = window.location.href;
    } else {
        $("#result").html(data);
    }
},
```

Comment: WOW! Thanks a lot. Can You explain me what is the difference between `data` and `data.trim()`? All works correctly even when i use only two equal signs, not three as you suggest. This is weird because in console returned data is without any space... each time.

Comment: `trim()` method  removes whitespace from both ends of a string

Comment: `if($login == 0) { echo '<div id="status" class="alert alert-'.$type.'">'.$error.'</div>'; } else echo 'logged';` As you see 'logged' text must always return without any whitespaces.. or maybe im wrong? of course in my php file this code is spread at couple lines.

Comment: Also check what's coming in response in the data variable. You could step through using debugger; command before the if statement. If you are using visual studio, you could set a breakpoint.

Comment: Try to do `console.log(data)` inside the success event and see what is the response you are getting.

Comment: @AbhijitAnnaldas I use only console from browser to check errors... each time returned data is correct based on php script...

Comment: @Shyju i do this from begining ... each time in console appear correct data as php script is sending... when use `console.log(data)`, in console all is printed fine without any whitepsaces